# Function misses exactly the squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

From Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel

**Problem:**

The function $f(n)=\lfloor n+\sqrt{n}+1 / 2\rfloor$ misses exactly the squares.

**Solution:**

Suppose $\lfloor n+\sqrt{n}+1 / 2\rfloor \neq m$. What can we say about $m \in \mathbb{N}$?
$$
\begin{aligned}
n+\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{2} & <m \text { and } \\
m+1 & <n+1+\sqrt{n+1}+\frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow \sqrt{n}<m-n-\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{n+1}, \\
n & <(m-n)^2-(m-n)+\frac{1}{4}<n+1 \Rightarrow n-\frac{1}{4} \\
& <(m-n)^2-(m-n)<n+\frac{3}{4}, \\
(m-n)^2-(m-n) & =n \Rightarrow m=(m-n)^2 .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now we make a simple counting argument: There are exactly $k$ squares $\leq k^2+k$ and exactly $k^2$ integers of the form $\lfloor n+\sqrt{n}+1 / 2\rfloor$. Thus $\lfloor n+\sqrt{n}+1 / 2\rfloor$ is the $n$th nonsquare.

**Question:**

I do not understand where this come from
$$m+1<n+1+\sqrt{n+1}+\frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$n<(m-n)^2-(m-n)+\frac{1}{4}<n+1$$

Comment: You'd have better luck with this question if you would give some context: Where did this proof come from i.e., wjhat textbook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof will be cleaner if we include $0$ in the domain and range of $f.$ This way, $f(0)=0$ hence (since $f$ is strictly increasing) an integer $m\ge0$ is missed by $f$ iff$$\exists n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}\quad f(n)<m<f(n+1).$$
Now, for every $m,n\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}:$

- $f(n)<m\iff n+\sqrt n+\frac12<m,$ and
- $m<f(n+1)\iff m+1\le n+1+\sqrt{n+1}+\frac12$ (note that the inequality here is *a priori* large, contrarily to what you report),

hence$$\begin{align}f(n)<m<f(n+1)&\iff n+\sqrt n+\frac12<m\le n+\sqrt{n+1}+\frac12\\
&\iff n<\left(m-n-\frac12\right)^2\le n+1\\
&\iff n<(m-n)^2-(m-n)+\frac14\le n+1\\
&\iff n\le(m-n)^2-(m-n)\le n\\
&\iff m=(m-n)^2,
\end{align}$$
provided $m>n$ for the second equivalence.

Therefore, every positive integer missed by $f$ is a square. Since we reasoned by equivalences, Engel's clever argument for the converse becomes unnecessary: just notice that for every $m,k\in\Bbb N,$
$$m=k^2\implies f(m-k)<m<f(m-k+1).$$

Comment: Very good answer.

Comment: Alternative solutions exist on AOPS, for example [this one](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2522454p21407887) found using https://approach0.xyz/

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you, I saw it but was not tempted to decipher it. And the OP's question was about Engel's solution.